# Mysql query to get data from 3 different tables for one userid

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea how to get data from one query with php mysql.

here is my try

```
$sthpre = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM users,
     file,
     friends
WHERE users.id='$other'
  AND file.user_id='$other'
  AND friends.user_id='$other'",$link) or die("Query  failed ");
```

i need to get for one user id i.e. 32 to get their binded values from other tables.

Comment: what is your result now and what you want?

Comment: Read PHP mysql_fetch_array() - http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: is that ok? i couldnt find any help

Comment: I think what you've written should work, but it's not how people usually write joins like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN to get results from more than one table

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  JOIN file ON file.user_id = users.id 
  JOIN friends ON friends.user_id = file.user_id
WHERE users.id = $other;
```

Please let me know if it worked

Comment: Why do you limit to one row?

Comment: since he want only one result, its good practice for performance

Comment: When did he say he only wanted to get one result? He said he wanted to get results for only one user.

Comment: QUERY FAILED, i need a tons of friends list for one user

Comment: please put die(mysql_error()) and give me the returned error .

Comment: how can i get for one user's records and these records' votes. so it will be three table in operation in same query?

for example : user1 has 3 records ( will be printed with names) and these records' votes in total for each

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN instead JOIN

Comment: Just add LEFT before JOIN that's it

Comment: @Saqueib i want to get follow table for user_id so i want to get foolower number count and following number count? at the same time with JOIN